# Dynamic Feature activity not loading, stuck at installation

Tags: android, generics, app-bundle, android-app-bundle

I am trying to implement app bundle for my project. On starting the dynamic module activity, it is downloading the module and trying to install the module, but is not able to completely install it. It gets stuck as in the image given below. 
[image]

Following the below link for reference. 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TextView
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.*
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.model.SplitInstallSessionStatus
import com.lenskart.app.R

private const val modulePackageName = "com.test.feature"

private const val htoClassname = "$modulePackageName.hto.HtoActivity"

private const val atHomeClassname = "$modulePackageName.athome.AtHomeActivity"

class BundleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val listener = SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener { state ->
        val multiInstall = state.moduleNames().size > 1
        state.moduleNames().forEach { name ->
            when (state.status()) {
                SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING -> {
                    displayLoadingState(state, "Downloading $name")
                }
                SplitInstallSessionStatus.REQUIRES_USER_CONFIRMATION -> {
                    startIntentSender(state.resolutionIntent().intentSender, null, 0, 0, 0)
                }
                SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED -> {
                    displayLoadingState(state, "Installed $name")
                    onSuccessfulLoad(name, launch = !multiInstall)
                }

                SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLING -> displayLoadingState(state, "Installing $name")
                SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: ${state.errorCode()} for module ${state.moduleNames()}")
                }

                SplitInstallSessionStatus.CANCELED -> displayLoadingState(state, "Cancelled $name")
                SplitInstallSessionStatus.UNKNOWN -> displayLoadingState(state, "Unknown thingy $name")
                SplitInstallSessionStatus.PENDING -> displayLoadingState(state, "Pending $name")

            }
        }
    }

    private val moduleHto by lazy { "hto" }
    private val moduleAtHome by lazy { "athome" }

    private lateinit var manager: SplitInstallManager

    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var progressText: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bundle)
        manager = SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(this)
        initializeViews()
        loadAndLaunchModule(moduleAtHome)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        manager.registerListener(listener)
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        manager.unregisterListener(listener)
        super.onPause()
    }

    private fun loadAndLaunchModule(name: String) {
        updateProgressMessage("Loading module $name")
        if (manager.installedModules.contains(name)) {
            updateProgressMessage("Already installed")
            onSuccessfulLoad(name, launch = true)
            return
        }
        val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
                .addModule(name)
                .build()

        manager.startInstall(request)

        updateProgressMessage("Starting install for $name")
    }

    private fun onSuccessfulLoad(moduleName: String, launch: Boolean) {
        if (true) {
            when (moduleName) {
                moduleHto -> launchActivity(htoClassname)
                moduleAtHome -> launchActivity(atHomeClassname)
            }
        }

        displayButtons()
    }

    private fun launchActivity(className: String) {
        Intent().setClassName(packageName, className)
                .also {
                    startActivity(it)
                }
    }

    private fun displayLoadingState(state: SplitInstallSessionState, message: String) {
        displayProgress()

        progressBar.max = state.totalBytesToDownload().toInt()
        progressBar.progress = state.bytesDownloaded().toInt()

        updateProgressMessage(message)
    }

    private fun initializeViews() {
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
        progressText = findViewById(R.id.progress_text)
    }

    private fun updateProgressMessage(message: String) {
        if (progressText.visibility != View.VISIBLE &&
                progressBar.visibility != View.VISIBLE) displayProgress()
        progressText.text = message
    }

    private fun displayProgress() {
        progressText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private fun displayButtons() {
        progressText.visibility = View.GONE
        progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }

}

private const val TAG = "DynamicFeatures"
```

Comment: I am also facing this issue, did you find any solution yet? Following the same reference https://github.com/googlesamples/android-dynamic-features.

Comment: same issue, any solution

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation, you also need to enable SplitCompat. You have 3 options for that:

- **Option 1: Use SplitCompatApplication as your default application by defining it in your AndroidManifest.xml**

  ```
  <application
      ...
      android:name="com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication" >
  </application>
  ```
- **Option 2: Have your current application class extend SplitCompatApplication.**

  ```
  public class MyApplication extends SplitCompatApplication {
      ...
  }
  ```
- **Option 3: Override the attachBaseContext method from your application.**

  ```
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
      super.attachBaseContext(context);
      // Emulates installation of future on demand modules using SplitCompat.
      SplitCompat.install(this);
  }
  ```

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore#declare_splitcompatapplication_in_the_manifest)

Comment: According to the documentation, we need to enable SplitCompat. But i don't see any  explanation how to do it in documents. Also in your shared link, it is not mentioned about SplitCompat.

Comment: It must have moved. Here it is: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand#access_downloaded_modules

Answer (score -2):

`@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
    }`

or

extends SplitCompatApplication

Comment: Your above code is wrong and does nothing at all.